# UIImage from object c to swift and image size bad

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, resize, image-resizing

i've a PNG image that i would insert into my navigation title.

In Object C i've

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_up.png"];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

it works very well and my image was in high quality

Then i create a similar APP in swift, using the same image, and write this code

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icons/logo_up.png"))
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width = 320
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height = 44
```

it print my image but with very poor quality.
I create different image with different size but nothing change. Every image in this APP have poor quality.
I use PNG and JPG extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the content mode of your `UIImageView`. You are changing the frame of the `UINavigationBar` in your Swift example, the image can be reduced in quality by doing this.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icons/logo_up.png"))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit //change contentMode
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()              self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width = 320
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height = 44
```

Comment: same problem ... quality image very poor and i don't understand why